# Kendo UI Calendar: Force multi-selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, calendar

The Kendo UI Calendar supports multi-selection: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/selection

However, the ctrl key needs to be held down in order to select multiple dates. If the user performs a regular click on the calendar, all existing dates will be cleared. I want the Calendar to always be in multi-selection mode, as if the ctrl key were always held down.

Kendo has an article here about doing just that: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/calendar-select-dates-click

But that doesn't work when the user clicks-and-drags over multiple dates (it only works for clicking on a single date at a time).

Is there a way to "override" the jQuery events and set their `ctrlKey` flag to true? Or is there a way to disable the click-and-drag feature that is messing up the second solution?

---- Update:

Don't use the workaround found in [this](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/calendar-select-dates-click) kendo article. It makes zooming out (to the month view) stop working. And the on-click handler leaks. Use the answer found below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unbind drag-related user events from the calendar's `selectable` module. You'd do something like this:

```
var ue = $("#calendar").getKendoCalendar().selectable.userEvents;
ue.unbind("start");
ue.unbind("move");
ue.unbind("end");
```

Alternatively if you want to keep the drag functionality, you could tweak the drag start by doing something like this:

```
var selectable = $("#calendar").getKendoCalendar().selectable;
selectable.userEvents.unbind("start");
selectable.userEvents.bind("start", function(e){
    e.target.removeClass("k-state-selected");
    e.event.ctrlKey = true;
    selectable._start(e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the alternative solution got what I wanted. I had to apply the same logic to the `move`, `end`, `select`, and `tap` events. I also took out the `removeClass('k-state-selected');` part. It was causing issues when clicking-and-dragging to deselect dates.